# I want to scrape from the bottom table at this website using Horseman and PhantomJS. What should I do?

Tags: node.js, scroll, web-scraping, phantomjs, node-horseman

The bottom table needs scrolling to show more data. This is the code that

Comment: If I were you, I'd better try to get the data directly from Angular Scope, instead of scrolling. That would give you speed and reliability.
If you open the page in Chrome DevTools, the following command in Console gives you the table date:
angular.element($('.ui-grid-canvas').get(0)).scope().rowContainer.visibleRowCache

Comment: @a-bobkov How can I do that in Node.js?

Comment: Horseman, which you are using, has a function "evaluate" - https://github.com/johntitus/node-horseman#evaluatefn-arg1-arg2

Comment: @a-bobkov It returns undefined. I updated the code above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a working example, the script below prints all "Listing #" from the table.
I hope, this helps.

```
var Horseman = require("node-horseman");
var horseman = new Horseman({timeout: 50000});

horseman
    .open("https://texans.seasonticketrights.com/Permanent-Seat-Licenses/For-Sale.aspx")
    .waitForSelector("div.ui-grid-cell-contents.ng-binding.ng-scope")
    .evaluate(function() {
        return angular.element($("div.ui-grid-canvas").get(0)).scope().rowContainer.visibleRowCache.map(function(listing) {return listing.entity.ListingID;}).join(',');
    })
    .then(function(listingIDs) {
        console.log(listingIDs);
    })
;
```